# Save UIImage as JPG to pass it to Microsoft Face API

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimage, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to pass all contacts from AddressBook to Cognitive Service Face Api to let people recognize if someone on photo that was taken using camera is the same person as is saved in AddressBook. 
As far as I know FaceApi allows JPG photos, but not UIImage's
How can I save Photo that I have as UIImage to directory and get place where it is stored into my dictionary where I have already added name of person from contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// convert a UIImage (img) into a JPEG stored in NSData
var data = img.AsJPEG(); 

// save NSData to file
data.Save(path);
```

Comment: Thanks, easy and fast :)